# Where to place this WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

the title might sound stupid but I didn't know what else to name it. So sorry about that in beforehand.

To my question. I found this old query that needs to be modified.

```
SELECT t.batchid, t.SQLidentity, t.qvardenum, t.kassorsakskod, t.editint, t.rowcreatedby
FROM dbo.qdin t
INNER JOIN (
SELECT batchid, max(sqlidentity) AS MaxId
FROM dbo.qdin
WHERE qparamid = 1
GROUP BY batchid)
tm on t.batchid = tm.batchid AND t.sqlidentity = tm.MaxId
```

I need to add column tiq.qparamgrupp and also a Where clause for it. I managed to join the table and add the column but I can't seem to be able to add a Where clause.

This is my query now.

```
SELECT t.batchid, 
       t.sqlidentity, 
       t.qvardenum, 
       t.kassorsakskod, 
       t.editint, 
       t.rowcreatedby, 
       tiq.qparamgrupp 
FROM   dbo.qdin t 
       INNER JOIN dbo.tiq 
               ON tiq.aonr = T.aonr 
                  AND tiq.aopos = T.aopos 
                  AND tiq.dummyuniqueid = T.conndummyuniqueid 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT batchid, 
                          Max(sqlidentity) AS MaxId 
                   FROM   dbo.qdin 
                   WHERE  qparamid = 1 
                   GROUP  BY batchid) tm 
               ON t.batchid = tm.batchid 
                  AND t.sqlidentity = tm.maxid 
WHERE  tiq.qparamgrupp = 2
```

and it returns nothing.

*EDIT*
This is part of the content.

```
qdin.batchid    qdin.qparamid   tiq.qparamgrupp qdin.qvardenum
(03-2020 10471)     1                  2             5,26
(03-2020 10471)     1                  3             5,23
(03-2020 10471)     2                  3             3290
(03-2020 10471)     2                  2             3400
(03-2020 10471)     3                  4              0
(03-2020 10471)     4                  2    
(03-2020 10471)     4                  3    
(03-2020 10471)     5                  3    
(03-2020 10471)     5                  2
```

If I run the query without the "WHERE  tiq.qparamgrupp = 2" I get this

```
qdin.batchid    qdin.qparamid   tiq.qparamgrupp qdin.qvardenum
(03-2020 10471)     1                  3             5,23
```

When I really want this.

```
qdin.batchid    qdin.qparamid   tiq.qparamgrupp qdin.qvardenum
(03-2020 10471)     1                  2             5,26
```

*EDIT2*
If I run this

```
SELECT t.batchid, t.qparamid, 
   t.sqlidentity, 
   t.qvardenum,  
   tiq.qparamgrupp 
FROM   dbo.qdin t 
   INNER JOIN dbo.tiq 
           ON tiq.aonr = T.aonr 
              AND tiq.aopos = T.aopos 
              AND tiq.dummyuniqueid = T.conndummyuniqueid 
              AND tiq.qparamgrupp = 2 
WHERE t.batchid = '03-2020 10471' AND t.qparamid = 1 AND tiq.qparamgrupp = 2
```

I get this

```
    batchid    qpramid    sqlidentity    qvardenum    qparamgrupp
03-2020 10471     1          32278       5.2600000         2
```

Which is good. But the problem is when I run another "batchid" and there's 2 records with same "qparamid" and "qparamgrupp". That's why I have "max(sqlidentity)" as I want the last record.

example

```
 SELECT t.batchid, t.qparamid, 
   t.sqlidentity, 
   t.qvardenum,  
   tiq.qparamgrupp 
FROM   dbo.qdin t 
   INNER JOIN dbo.tiq 
           ON tiq.aonr = T.aonr 
              AND tiq.aopos = T.aopos 
              AND tiq.dummyuniqueid = T.conndummyuniqueid 
              AND tiq.qparamgrupp = 2 
WHERE t.batchid = '03-2020 10470' AND t.qparamid = 1 AND tiq.qparamgrupp = 2
```

Gives me this

```
    batchid    qpramid    sqlidentity    qvardenum    qparamgrupp
03-2020 10470     1          32112       5.2300000         2   
03-2020 10470     1          32235       5.3000000         2
```

Is there a easier way or another way to write this so that I only get

```
03-2020 10470     1          32235       5.3000000         2
```

?

Thanks in advance

SisU

Comment: Your query seem to be ok. The most like it is there arent any rows with `qparamgrupp = 2` on that join. Try remove the second join and check if you have any result. If you have, then check if those have a match with the second join. Also you can try using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: It could be because any of your JOINS or WHERE clause find no matches. Try without where condition first. Even then its not giving you results, visit your JOINS one by one.

Comment: Edited with some of the content.

Comment: Can it be because I want MAX sqlidentity in subquery and that don't match with the the outher clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this now and just wanted to post my answer. Thanks all for your help.

```
SELECT t.batchid, 
   t.qparamid, 
   t.sqlidentity, 
   t.qvardenum,  
   tiq.qparamgrupp 
FROM   dbo.qdin t 
   INNER JOIN dbo.tiq 
           ON tiq.aonr = T.aonr 
              AND tiq.aopos = T.aopos 
              AND tiq.dummyuniqueid = T.conndummyuniqueid
WHERE 
t.sqlidentity = (SELECT
Max(sqlidentity) AS MaxID 
FROM dbo.qdin t
   JOIN dbo.tiq 
           ON tiq.aonr = T.aonr 
              AND tiq.aopos = T.aopos 
              AND tiq.dummyuniqueid = T.conndummyuniqueid
WHERE t.batchid = '03-2020 10470' AND t.qparamid = 1 AND
tiq.qparamgrupp = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   SELECT t.batchid, 
       t.sqlidentity, 
       t.qvardenum, 
       t.kassorsakskod, 
       t.editint, 
       t.rowcreatedby, 
       tiq.qparamgrupp 
FROM   dbo.qdin t 
       INNER JOIN dbo.tiq 
               ON tiq.aonr = T.aonr 
                  AND tiq.aopos = T.aopos 
                  AND tiq.dummyuniqueid = T.conndummyuniqueid 
                  AND tiq.qparamgrupp = 2 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT batchid, 
                          Max(sqlidentity) AS MaxId 
                   FROM   dbo.qdin 
                   WHERE  qparamid = 1 
                   GROUP  BY batchid) tm 
               ON t.batchid = tm.batchid 
                  AND t.sqlidentity = tm.maxid
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However this gave me 0 results as well. I've updated my question (EDIT2).

Comment: if you can Insert your data with sqlfiddle.com I will find your answer, I at lease need the create table statement for the involved tables, and it would be nice to have insert statements for the sample data you are displaying, what it feels like there is a field common to the 2 tables that is not on the join clause

Comment: I'm not sure how to use sqlfiddle. I did a SELECT INTO NEWTABLE and tried to script the create table with SSMS. But I don't seem to be able to create the table with the query the script gives me? PS: Sorry for late response.